# Unity. transform.SetParent() is Launching my player across the map for no reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, parent-child

I'm trying to make a moving platform for my platformer. As soon as my player touches the platform, it becomes the child of the platform but the player FLIES across the scene almost instantly. The platform is in place but the player just teleports away. I tried simplifying this and using another script for the moving platform.

This is the whole script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePltfrmTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

Also I don't think this happens with other gameobjects. I have some treasure gameobjects and they work normally.

Comment: It might be important to distinguish if the player thrown away continously by an undesired collision or teleported by a position change

Answer (score 2):

You can use `...transform.SetParent(transform,true)` to preserve the player's world position when setting his parent transform ([Explanation from Unity's docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)).

You're having this issue because `Transform` positions are stored relative to their parent (Hence the name `Transform` they are representative of a series of matrix transformations that scale, rotate and translate a coordinate value). By changing the parent, the players position is now a combination of the transformation implied by their `transform` **and their parent's**.

When you pass `true` to `SetParent`'s second paramater, Unity changes the player's transform so that it's overall position in the world will be preserved when it becomes relative to the platform's transform.